# How to open a FILE in a C program?Where do we have to create a file?

Tags: c, file

How to open a FILE in a C program?Where do we have to create a file?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "where to we have to create a file?"

Comment: You might have tried searching for similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395842/c-output-to-file, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808374/c-file-operation-question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739392/opening-a-file-and-outputting-in-c ...

Comment: Is this a coincidence, are there three different persons named stefideltz on SO? Or is this just a one time service for you?

Answer (score 4):

You normally open a file with `fopen`. I'm not sure what "Where do we have to create a file?" means.